# What is the win ratio of spies and resistant in The Resistance?

Tags: the-resistance

I have been playing that game for a while now (mostly the wikipedia version), and I have the impression that the game is extremely imbalanced. In my circle of friend, the win ratio is about 80% for the spies. Is there any statistical data that gives a broader win ratio?

Comment: The win ratio might change if you add Plot cards.

Comment: You'll also find that the win ratio for the resistance improves as players become more experienced and learn how to overcome their information gap.

Comment: I say it would (very) largely depend on the group, their experience, and how many players there are. A lot of the game is all about reading players. Similar to poker, it's easier to read people you know rather than complete strangers. Therefore the only real way to determine actual win % would be to record statistics in games where the players don't know each other.

Comment: It sounds like your group hasn't learned to play Resistance very well yet. Playing a spy, at a basic level, is pretty straightforward. Playing a Resistance member takes a little more thought. After all, the spies already know everything; they're just trying to create confusion and mislead. The Resistance members have to piece together the information. Stick with it and the Resistance will probably improve.

Comment: The question is not about learning to play the game, please do not make assumption about the gaming group.

Comment: @Saffron, in order to answer the question the game group itself has to be assessed; as you will have a much different answer if the game group is fairly new to the game compared to expert players.

Comment: I would start looking at voting patterns and how you vote when you are playing good. A common mistake I have seen from newer players is voting for a mission where it is impossible to win such as the last mission requiring all of the good members to be on the team and yet good members not on the team (meaning there has to be an evil member on the team) voting for the mission to proceed. One thing to try is if you like the overall idea of the game is to pick up the resistance avalon as it give the good side some more knowledge (as well as another way for evil to win)

Answer (score 2):

This [thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/608453/reviewing-100-plays-statistics) provides the statistics you seem to be looking for, but with anything, correlation never implies causation. The OP came to the conclusion that your commenters did; the game is fairly balanced, and you really do need to assess the playstyle and strategies of your gaming group. Thing is, the best part of the Resistance is after the game itself is over.